# How to keep two columns in one row when I change browser size?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have row with two columns and on the left col is text and on the right is image.
And the problem is than when I changing browser size then image goes down and I want to keep those in one row.

here HTML code:

```css
#features {
      margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    #row {
      margin: 27px 15px 10px 0px;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    #features_text {
      margin-left: 300px;
      margin-top: 43px;
      width: 27%;
    }
    
    
    .features_p {
      font-size: 24px;
      color: #0a3441;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
      margin-left: 72px;
    }
    
    #features_image {
      background-image: url(../images/gif_image.jpg);
      width: 992px;
      height: 599px;
      float: right;
      margin-left: 0;
      margin-right: -21px;
    }
```

```html
 <div id="features">
      <div class="row" id="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6" id="features_text">
          <p class="features_p">Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</p>
          <p class="features_p">Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</p>
          <p class="features_p">Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</p>
          <p class="features_p">Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6" id="features_image">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing BS styles with your own too much. If you're using BS then you shouldn't use certain own styles but if you need to use this much your own styles then don't use BS classes. Ie. here you have set the col-sm-6 classes but you are redefining the widths and margins with your own styles and it makes using BS classes unnecessary.

If you want to have columns always with 1/3 and 2/3 width then your code should be

```
<div id="features">
  <div class="row" id="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4" id="features_text">
      <p class="features_p">Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</p>
      <p class="features_p">Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</p>
      <p class="features_p">Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</p>
      <p class="features_p">Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8" id="features_image">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And remove the widths, left & right margin and float from the #features_text and #features_image styles. Also remove left & right margin and width styles from #row.

```
#row {
  margin-top: 27px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#features_text {
  /* Nothing here */
}

#features_image {
  background-image: url(../images/gif_image.jpg);
  height: 599px;
}
```

I'm not sure why you are using the the image as a background-image if you have nothing else there. You could also put it in the div with just as a image and add BS classes to it so it scales down.

```
<img src="yourimage.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
```

Here's a fiddle link with clean code: https://jsfiddle.net/02gp4tL7/1/

You should use the BS structure which is .container > .row > .col-sm-X to get the margins and paddings right. If you want to customize the view then add your own styles but add it so that you take in consideration the BS styles also.

Comment: I will check it. Could you show this in jsfiddle please?

Comment: Added a link and some.

Comment: Thanks! But the think is the text must be spaced from the left but not on center like between those.

Comment: What do you mean 'spaced from the left but not on center'? It has to have padding on both sides? Just add padding: 0 30px; to the #features p style definition, for example.

Comment: Good. I recommend reading more about using Bootstrap and good way to learn it is checking their examples.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set `col-xs-6` for each of them instead of `col-sm-6`, thus they will occupy half of window width for any viewport, including extrasmall ones:

```
<div id="features">
  <div class="row" id="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 text-center" id="features_text">
      <p class="features_p">Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</p>
      <p class="features_p">Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</p>
      <p class="features_p">Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</p>
      <p class="features_p">Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6" id="features_image">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! But the think is the text must be spaced from the left but not on center like between those.

Comment: added `text-center` class. now the text will be centered in the left column.